How to implement two-factor authentication in SPA application with ASP.NET Core 8.0 identity as backend
I'm trying to use all the new features in ASP.NET Core 8.
I'm using this code
using IspH2H.Engine;
using IspH2H.Engine.Entities;
using IspH2H.WebAPI.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options));


builder.Services.Configure<SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration.SmtpEmailSender));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<IspH2HIdentityUser>, SmtpEmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IspH2HContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IspH2HIdentityUser>(opt =>
    {
        opt.User = new UserOptions
        {
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        opt.Password = new PasswordOptions
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequiredUniqueChars = 0,
            RequireNonAlphanumeric = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
            RequireDigit = true
        };
        opt.Lockout = new LockoutOptions
        {
            AllowedForNewUsers = false,
            MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3,
            DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) // 8 hours lockout
        };
        opt.SignIn = new SignInOptions
        {
            RequireConfirmedEmail = true,
            //RequireConfirmedAccount = true
        };
        // opt.Tokens = new TokenOptions() { };
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IspH2HContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "IspH2H.WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
    opt.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "bearer"
    });

    opt.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Adds the endpoint
    // /migrate
    // for migrations
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint(new MigrationsEndPointOptions
    {
        Path = "/migrate"
    });


    app.MapGet("/contexts", (HttpContext context) =>
    {
        var registeredContextNames = context.RequestServices.GetServices<DbContextOptions>()
            .Select(o => o.ContextType.AssemblyQualifiedName).ToList();
        return registeredContextNames;
    });


    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapIdentityApi(); // New in.net 8, it adds all the authentication endpoints

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

to configure ASP.NET Core identity and add endpoints.
At the end I can see the endpoint in Swagger:

but I can't find documentation for calls.

You need to handle the two factor authentication in the swagger controller : https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/assign-specific-authorization-scheme-to-endpoint-in-swagger-ui-in-net-core-cd84d2a2ebd7

The ASP.NET Core Identity default UI includes a page for configuring 2FA. For more information about Identity integration with the Web API backend of SPA, you can refer to this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0
For more information about enabling and using 2FA, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0
